# GWT HashMap to/from JSON

Tags: json, gwt

I might be getting a bit tired tonight but here it goes:

I'd like to have GWT HashMap to/from JSON.  How would I achieve this?

In other words, I'd like to take an `HashMap`, take its JSON representation, store it somewhere and get it back to its native Java representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not the most optimized, but should be easy to code: use `JSONObject`.

Iterate over your map's entries and `put` them in a `JSONObject` (converting each value to a `JSONValue` of the appropriate type), then call `toString` to get the JSON representation.

For parsing, get a `JSONObject` back using a `JSONParser`, then iterate over the `keySet`, `get`ing the values and putting them in your map (after unwrapping the `JSONValue`s)

But beware of the keys you use! You cannot use any kind of key as a property name in JS; and JSON processing in the browser always involve going through a JS object (or implementing the JSON parser yourself, which won't perform the same)

Comment: I used a solution along those lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Here is my quick solution:

```
public static String toJson(Map<String, String> map) {
    String json = "";
    if (map != null && !map.isEmpty()) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: map.entrySet()) {
            jsonObj.put(entry.getKey(), new JSONString(entry.getValue()));
        }
        json = jsonObj.toString();
    }
    return json;
}

public static Map<String, String> toMap(String jsonStr) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    JSONValue parsed = JSONParser.parseStrict(jsonStr);
    JSONObject jsonObj = parsed.isObject();
    if (jsonObj != null) {
        for (String key : jsonObj.keySet()) {
            map.put(key, jsonObj.get(key).isString().stringValue());
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

Comment: one would probably want to use jsonObj.get(key).isString().stringValue() 
instead of
jsonObj.get(key).toString()
otherwise will end up with values inside ""