# HashMap to JsonSting?

Tags: java, json, gwt, hashmap

I am working on a GWT application.

I want to convert a hashMap to JSON String and send it to GWT server

My HashMap is like `HashMap<String, CustomProperties)`

CustomProperties is the class with different parameters. This HashMap is property of file .

I want to uplaod a file with these properties.

What I am going to do : Attach the json Sting to hidden field and send it with the file through the formPanel.

But I dont know how to do Hashmap to JSON String.

Can anyone guide me in this regard ?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278471/gwt-hashmap-to-from-json/14654318#14654318

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [GWT AutoBean](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean) framework for serializing to and from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

JohnS' answer makes sense. 
However, there is a related and a long ago answered question: [GWT HashMap to/from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278471/gwt-hashmap-to-from-json) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You could give Jackson a try.

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
mapper.writeValue(outputStream, yourMap);
yourMapinJson=outputStream.toString();
```